Как создать эффект вспышки на CSS JavaScript?
увидел на одном сайте интересный эффект.
Скажите, пожалуйста, друзья у кого есть какие мысли как это можно сделать с помощью CSS или JS?
Эффект дыма от курсора при движении курсора.
Сам эффект могу только показать:


Посмотри тут пример:
https://codepen.io/DedaloD/pen/abLmBxJ или https://codepen.io/DedaloD/pen/PoJGKOb

Вот еще пример: https://codepen.io/Irehan/pen/YgyozL

@HappyPM, благодарю :-)
